# Backing up Word VBA Macros

Tags: microsoft-word, backup, vba

I just inadvertently deleted a couple of functions that I needed and am having to recreate them.  Is there a way to back up Word VBA macros themselves?  Preferably one that's quick and easy and/or automatic, if such a thing exists.

I know they all reside in the Normal template, so backing that up on a regular basis could work.

Comment: Export them. That's about it with VBA. I suggest just using version control on documents like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the VBE to export and import your modules -

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar Quesiton [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742583/backing-up-vba-project).

Matt's Mug mentioned a Source Control Software call Rubberduck.

I originally backed-up each individual Module in my Project, as it was stored in the "Normal" template and yes you can find the location of the Word "Normal" template and then copy that.

However, I then copied all the Modules into a New Word Document, which I then saved as a Macro Enabled Template. With this I could then save it in Dropbox or where and then before making major changes to the code I then just played with a copy of the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed export the modules manually from the IDE, or using an add-in like RubberDuck.

But you're not compelled to keep your Macros in Normal.dot. You can keep VBA that is specific to a document within the document itself. If you're recording Macros, simply choose where you want the Macro recorded to when you start recording. If you're typing the VBA by hand, just add a Module to your Document within the VBA IDE.

Once the VBA is inside the document, you just need to backup the documents that you've changed. This has the benefit of keeping the document structure and the code that operates on that structure inline.